# Correct usage of "in that"

Tags: parts-of-speech

I've heard *in that* used as a synonym for *because*, but I don't think that this is semantically correct in all cases.

> That car is nice, **in that** it is blue.

This sentence generally makes sense to me, but it also sounds funny. But I don't know enough of the technicalities of English to diagnose the problem.

It's hard to research this because I don't know what the correct part-of-speech term is for *in that*. I want to call it a *phrase* but I think some of you will cringe if I do this.

Can someone give examples of when and when not to use *in that*, or point to a resource that can explain it?

Comment: In that can be the key word for an adverb clause, I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that *because* is a statement of causality, while *in that* is used to describe a relationship or a perception.

> The car's steering was off because an accident had bent one of the tie rods.
>
> The car's steering was off in that I could feel a slight wobble even when driving on level, flat pavement.

In the second example, you wouldn't use *because* because the symptom is not the cause. In the first example you wouldn't use *in that* because the bent tie rod is a direct cause, not a perception (unless it involved speculation, which here it does not).

I think of *in that* as a shorter form of *in the sense that* (or *to the degree that*) something appears to be a certain way.

Answer (score 4):

It would be pretty odd to say *"That car is nice, in that it is blue"* unless you were speaking to someone who knew that you had a (probably extreme) predeliction for the colour blue.

I don't quite agree with @Robusto's implication that *because* can't substitute for *in that*. It often can, in that/because there's often no real difference between whether the statement preceding it is something *literally caused by the 'subsidiary statement' following*, or "metaphorically" comes to be *true from the perspective of the subsidiary*.

To my mind, the primary difference is that *in that* is a somewhat "formal" construction, primarily used in writing rather than speech.

A secondary difference concerns the fact that, as Robusto says, it can usually be replaced by *in the sense that*. If it seems reasonable in context to replace by **only** or **specifically** *in the sense that*, you almost certainly couldn't use *because* instead.